# Encoder (codec none) not found for output stream #0:1

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Hi i built ffmpeg executable on Redhat5. I want to mix two Audio using the command multiple
"ffmpeg -i INPUT1 -i INPUT2 -i INPUT3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=3:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 OUTPUT.mp3".

I enabled libflamemp3 library without any error.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ffmpeg -i /root/media/Katlalli.mp3 -i /root/media/Katlalli.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2 /root/media/OUTPutnew123.mp3
ffmpeg version 2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 14 2013 03:17:10 with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
  configuration: --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      52. 48.100 / 52. 48.100
  libavcodec     55. 39.100 / 55. 39.100
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
[mp3 @ 0x193ef240] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '/root/media/Katlalli.mp3':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Yograj Bhat
    title           : Katlalli Karadige
    track           : 3
    album           : Paramathma
    album_artist    : Puneet Rajkumar
    genre           : Kannada
    composer        : V.Harikrishna
    date            : 2011
  Duration: 00:04:41.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 191 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 200x200 [SAR 96:96 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : thumbnail
      comment         : Cover (front)
[mp3 @ 0x194090a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from '/root/media/Katlalli.mp3':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Yograj Bhat
    title           : Katlalli Karadige
    track           : 3
    album           : Paramathma
    album_artist    : Puneet Rajkumar
    genre           : Kannada
    composer        : V.Harikrishna
    date            : 2011
  Duration: 00:04:41.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 191 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #1:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 200x200 [SAR 96:96 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : thumbnail
      comment         : Cover (front)
File '/root/media/OUTPutnew123.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp3, to '/root/media/OUTPutnew123.mp3':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Yograj Bhat
    title           : Katlalli Karadige
    track           : 3
    album           : Paramathma
    album_artist    : Puneet Rajkumar
    genre           : Kannada
    composer        : V.Harikrishna
    date            : 2011
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1: Video: none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      title           : thumbnail
      comment         : Cover (front)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mp3) -> amix:input0
  Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> amix:input1
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mjpeg -> ?)
Encoder (codec none) not found for output stream #0:1
```

But when i try to combine two mp3 audio, 
"ffmpeg -i INPUT1 -i INPUT2 -i INPUT3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=3:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 OUTPUT.mp3".

I am getting error like

"Encoder (codec none) not found for output stream #0:1"

so please help me how to link or install "libmp3flame" on Redhat5.

Comment: Please include the complete ffmpeg console output; otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Hi LordNeckbeard thanks for your quick reply. I edited my question please go through and give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### zlib

I believe ffmpeg is trying to decode a PNG input video stream (the album art) and encode the output video stream to PNG output, but I assume you built ffmpeg without zlib support which is required for PNG encoding and decoding.

zlib is automatically detected if available, so you needed to install the zlib headers prior to ffmpeg compilation (`zlib-devel` package for Red Hat 'n friends).

#### omit video

Alternatively you can keep your build and tell ffmpeg to ignore any video with the `-vn` output option.

#### use `mjpeg`

If you want to keep your build and also keep the album art then add `-codec:v mjpeg` as an output option. See [stream selection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) to see which of the two inputs ffmpeg will choose.

#### use `-codec:v copy`

You can also [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the video with `-codec:v copy`. This is probably preferable over re-encoding with `-codec:v mjpeg`. See [stream selection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) to see which of the two inputs ffmpeg will choose. If you add `-map 0 -map 1` then both video streams will be included.

#### also see

- [Compile FFmpeg on CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide)

Comment: I am not sending any video input there. Just i want to mix two audios.

Comment: I am not sending any video input there. I am sending two mp3 audio's to mix. By using the same ffmpeg executable i am able trim the video and audio, but I am not able to mix the audio. Many people suggested to enable "libmp3lame" I enabled that also "libmp3lame"  but no result. Is there any link i can get ffmpeg executable so that i can use that executable directly in my android project to mix two audio's.

Comment: @Gururak Your inputs contain video (the album art image), and that is where the problem is. Look at your console output. `Encoder (codec none) not found for output stream #0:1` indicates that there is a problem when encoding output stream `0:1`. Then `Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mjpeg -> ?)` shows that ffmpeg does not know what to do with the video stream. Any one of the four solutions I provided will make your command work.

Comment: Yes LordNeckBeard its working great after using "-vn". Can i use same executable for my android project to add two audio's?.

Comment: I desperately need your help in this issue. I want to mix not concatenate two mp3 audio files in android using ffmpeg executable. I am using the same command what i used earlier like "ffmpeg -i INPUT1 -i INPUT2 -i INPUT3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=3:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 OUTPUT.mp3" but its not working. But its working for other tasks like trimming ideo and audio but not for mixxing audio please help me. I am trying this    since a week but i dint get aby result. please suggest some commands or how to create ffmpeg executable for Android with libmp3lame.

Comment: @Gururak Why do people describe the problem as "not working" instead of showing actual error messages?

Comment: yeah you are right, but I am not getting any error messages in logcat otherwise I would have shown on this stack overflow. I am using "https://github.com/JayH5/android-ffmpeg-cmdline" example, there is an executable ffmpeg to which i am sending commands in my code. Or please guide me how to build ffmpeg executable for android with libmp3lame. I will try my level best to post errors on this account.

Comment: @Gururak Without the actual ffmpeg command and the complete console output there is nothing I can do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got ffmpeg executable for android and i got the output :-).

Comment: @Gururak I gave you four solutions to the `Encoder (codec none) not found` problem. If you are experiencing a different issue please ask a new question at [su].